# How does one disconnect from a network share in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

As a Mac user, I would expect this to be as simple as right-clicking the share and selecting "Disconnect", but it appears we are not to be so lucky.

To be clear, this is the kind of share where you open the start menu, type `\\servername\share`, enter credentials, and the server and share appear in the sidebar under "Network".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete all sessions 
`net use * /del`

Delete only one session
`net use \\servername\share /del`

Show actual sessions
`net use`

From users standpoint, it's easier to `Map Network Drive` from `My Computer`. Then it only takes right click and `Disconnect`.

Comment: You beat me to it. I can't type that quickly :-)

Answer (score 4):

When you just enter an UNC path as you describe, you're not connecting anything permanently, so there's nothing to "Disconnect" -- the server will drop the connection after it's been idle for a bit.

If you had mapped/mounted it as a drive letter, then you could "Disconnect" the mapping as you suggest, or how @week suggested in their answer.  But you're not mapping it, you're just entering the (UNC) path for the one-time use.

Windows may be kind enough to remember the fact you used it, remember the related credentials, and offer it in dialogs and such, but it's just a remembered path, not a mounted connection.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I made that assumption because I saw errors like "Windows cannot connect multiple times to the same resource; please disconnect and try again" -- or something like that.